# Problem with Quarto automated referencing of book sections

Tags: r-markdown, quarto, csl, pandoc-citeproc

I am using Quarto on R Studio to create an HTML book for my thesis. The Insert -> @Citation function works great and is automatically integrated with Zotero, however, I am having some issues when referencing books/conference proceedings.

The name of the chapter goes missing, or the name of the book. Example:

Citation automatically created with quarto:

> Wright, P.J., 2010. Methodological issues in paleoethnobotany: A consideration of issues, methods, and cases. In: VanDerwarker, A.M., Peres, T.M. (Eds.),. Springer New York, New York, NY, pp. 37–64.

Citation exported from Zotero:

> Wright, P.J., 2010. Methodological Issues in Paleoethnobotany: A consideration of Issues, Methods, and Cases. In: VanDerwarker, A.M., Peres, T.M. (Eds.), Integrating Zooarchaeology and Paleoethnobotany: A Consideration of Issues, Methods, and Cases. Springer New York, New York, NY, pp. 37–64.

.BIB automatically generated when importing in RStudio
[image: Bib file]

This happens either if I specify a .CSL (and I tried with several citation styles) in the YAML or not. If I load these .CSL into Zotero and I try to export a report the citation is however correct.

I did not create a reproducible example as I feel this is a 'general' issue, so I wasn't sure how to make it.

Is anyone experiencing similar issues?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I did find a way to work around this issue.

From the R Studio Tools menu, open 'Global Options' -> R Markdown -> Citations -> select 'Use BetterBibTex'

Note: This makes the insertion significantly slower somehow and requires the Zotero app to be open at all times. Moreover it seems to ignore my citation style customizations (for instance name of the journal in italics when citing an article). It's a first step