# Problem with Quarto citation: referencing of book sections

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown, quarto, citations

I use Quarto for scholarly writing and I have a problem with the citations.
I've noticed that the referencing of book sections doesn't work when I use a custom citation style (`csl: *.csl`). If I choose a citation style with `bibliographystyle: apa`, however, there are no problems.

For an example, see the image. This is the entry in Zotero.
The output with `bibliographystyle: apa` is:

If I import this entry with Quarto/RStudio into my script (better: into `bibliography.bib` file), the bibtex:

```
@inbook{beck2020a,
    title = {Ein Tabu mit gewaltigen Konsequenzen. Geschlechtsbasierte personale Gewalt in politischen Institutionen},
    author = {Beck, Dorothee},
    editor = {Beck, Dorothee and Henninger, Annette},
    year = {2020},
    date = {2020},
    publisher = {Ulrike Helmer Verlag},
    pages = {165--188},
    series = {Reihe Geschlecht zwischen Vergangenheit und Zukunft des Zentrums für Gender Studies und Feministische Zukunftsforschung der Philipps-Universität Marburg},
    number = {Band 9},
    note = {OCLC: on1204200688},
    address = {Rossdorf},
    langid = {ger eng}
}
```

There is the first bug: obviously the `booktitle` is not part of the bibtex, although it's part of the database entry.

The second bug is that even if the `booktitle` is in the bibtex, it's not expressed in output if I use a custom citation style via `csl: *.csl`.
At the same time, it's not a bug of the citation style, as it works in MS Word -- the program I was working with before I discovered Quarto.

This solution does not work for me, because Better BibTeX doesn't work: [Problem with Quarto automated referencing of book sections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73279162/problem-with-quarto-automated-referencing-of-book-sections)